# System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException error

Tags: sql-server-2008, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple MVC 5 test solution that is connected to a SQL server 2008 on the intranet here. I have followed this tutorial so far:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/generating-views

I can open the view, and it shows the listing but when I try to create a new one I get the following error:

> {"Unable to update the EntitySet 'Movies' because it has a
>   DefiningQuery and no `<InsertFunction>` element exists in the
>   `<ModificationFunctionMapping>` element to support the current
>   operation."}

I used the Database first approach so I have no idea what has gone wrong. I understand that somehow he can't perform an Update. Is this something I need to fix inside the project or has it to do something with SQl server?

EDIT: here is the exception details

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=Unable to update the EntitySet 'Movies' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
       at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
       at TestSite.Controllers.MoviesController.Create(Movy movy) in c:\Users\Rovc\Desktop\TestSite\TestSite\Controllers\MoviesController.cs:line 54
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
  InnerException: System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException
       HResult=-2146232032
       Message=Unable to update the EntitySet 'Movies' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.
       Source=EntityFramework.SqlServer
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlGen.DmlSqlGenerator.ExpressionTranslator.Visit(DbScanExpression expression)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbScanExpression.Accept(DbExpressionVisitor visitor)
            at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlGen.DmlSqlGenerator.GenerateInsertSql(DbInsertCommandTree tree, SqlGenerator sqlGenerator, List`1& parameters, Boolean generateReturningSql, Boolean upperCaseKeywords, Boolean createParameters)
            at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlGen.SqlGenerator.GenerateSql(DbCommandTree tree, SqlVersion sqlVersion, List`1& parameters, CommandType& commandType, HashSet`1& paramsToForceNonUnicode)
            at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateCommand(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
            at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommand(DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.CreateCommand(DbModificationCommandTree commandTree)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.CreateCommand(Dictionary`2 identifierValues)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35()
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27()
            at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
            at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
       InnerException:
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. The table that I was using was apparently missing a primary key. Once I designated the correct field as Primary everything worked.

Comment: Also, it is important to not forget to update your database model *.edmx file.  See http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2010/05/31/unable-to-update-the-entityset-because-it-has-a-definingquery.aspx for details.

Comment: Yeah I always keep that on up to date since I had an other issue a while ago, but for some reason the primary key was not defined in the EDMX yet.